# How to run snippets of JavaScript code in Node environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js

### Scenario:

Say I have a JavaScript file that I run in Node environment like this:

```
// Import components from somewhere
import Something from './Somewhere';

const a = () => {
  // Define function a here
};

const b = () => {
  // Define function b here
};

outputA = a();

outputB = b();
```

### Question

How can I run only part of the code in Node? (Or is there a way?)

For example, I only want to run `outputB = b();`, but not `outputA = a()`. However, I'd like to run the code snippet in this JavaScript file's context, i.e., imported components and function definitions.

This is similar to "[Run Snippets Of JavaScript On Any Page With Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/snippets)", but I wonder if there is a way to run snippets of code in Node environment, presumably in the terminal.

Comment: You can't run only part of the code unless you read the file into memory, modify the code dynamically and then execute it with `eval()`.  Without modifying the code to remove or comment out the stuff you don't want to run, there is no way to run only part of it.

Comment: Do you know is there an IDE or an extension of some sort on a text editor that can achieve it?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for.  You can load the text into a Javascript string and use regex matching to find code and modify things.  I'm not sure why you're asking for a text editor.  You can use any text editor you want to manually edit the code.

Comment: Say I'm testing or debugging a small section, or adding a little bit of new code into a JavaScript file that has a thousand lines. I could use a debugger or a unit test to help me with the process. But I just thought, it would be helpful if there is another way that allows me to run snippets of codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could technically use vscode debugger. It will load your code and stop on the breakpoint. From there it gives you a terminal to copy paste part of the code and run it. Or change inputs and re-run parts of the code. It’s a very powerful tool.

Resource:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging